# Why did not show the number of counts of the unique character value

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Y6i.jpg)
The y-axis "number of rides" didn't show the count of ride_id ( ride_id is a unique character value). Anyone can help me to explain why it happened and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: From the image i deduce you're seeing the previous plot. See the title of the plot.
If so, please delete the post.

Comment: What do you think the number of rides should be? From the environment tab we can see your data has about 5M rows, so 400k rides in July seems reasonable.

Comment: Do you just not like the `e` scientific notation? Maybe add `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma())` to your plot to stop the scientific notation.

Comment: If you need more help, please explain the problem more clearly, and please post your code as text, not as a screenshot. And a little bit (say 20 rows) of sample data also posted as copy/pasteable text would help a lot

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by *"ride_id is a unique character value"*. This is incorrect. We can see in your screenshot that you define `ride_id = n()`, thus `ride_id` is integer, not character, and there is nothing enforcing uniqueness (nor should there be).

Comment: Thank you, there seems to be a bit of confusion from me as I am a newbie. Now I know my problem